# Cascading drop down list in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I'm still new in Power Apps,

I'm facing the issue when two drop-down list displays by using Office 365 Group connector.

when 1st drop-down list change, then second drop-down list change accordingly.

The 1st drop-down list Formula is **Office365Groups.ListOwnedGroupsV3().value.displayName**

The 2nd drop-down list Formula is **Office365Groups.ListOwnedGroups().value.id**

The data should be:

Group Name - Group ID

1. Titanic - 340axxxx
2. DevSpace - a985xxx

Herewith my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solving by using the following formula.

**Filter(Office365Groups.ListOwnedGroupsV3().value.id, id = ddlgrouptest.Selected.id)**

ddlgrouptest is my first dropdownlist name.